# Combining multiple `Try` instances of different result types as applicatives

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, vavr

Is there an api for combining `Try` instances in Vavr that is similar to the way the Scalaz applicative operator `|@|` works?

Specifically, if I have more than two `Try` instances, for example, `Try<X>`, `Try<Y>` and `Try<Z>`, I would like to combine these instances in an applicative fashion using a 3-arg function.

I'm looking for a function signature that is similar to:

```
static <X, Y, Z, R> Try<R> combine(Try<X> x, Try<Y> y, Try<Z> z, Function3<X,Y,Z,R> func
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see it doesn't support that usage directly. You can, however, achieve it using flatMap:

```
static <X, Y, Z, R> Try<R> combine(Try<X> tx, Try<Y> ty, Try<Z> tz, Function3<X,Y,Z,R> func) {
    return tx.flatMap(x -> ty.flatMap(y -> tz.map(z -> func.apply(x, y, z))));
}
```

If each Try value contains the same type then you can use a `sequence` operation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Try<String>> lt = List.of(Try.success("A"), Try.success("B"), Try.success("C"));
    Try<List<String>> tl = sequence(lt);
    System.out.println(tl);
}

static <T> Try<List<T>> sequence(List<Try<T>> lt) {
    return lt.foldRight(
        Try.success(List.empty()),
        (tt, tl) -> tt.flatMap(t -> tl.flatMap(l -> Try.success(l.prepend(t))))
    );
}
```

If you compare the input and output types you can see this essentially swaps the position of the `Try` and `List` containers. It's fairly idiomatic for monads, though typically you would implement it with applicative map operations instead of flatMap.

Alternatively, use [Validation](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_validation), which is designed to be used in an applicative style (via `Validation.combine`).

Comment: Yeah, although for more than 3 `Try` instances, those nested `flatMap` calls can get a bit hairy!
I could use `Validation`, but it doesn't seem to be a good fit for my use case (except for the applicative syntax it supports). Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe I could write a convenience method that does exactly what you've suggested :thinking-face:

Comment: @diveshpremdeep I've edited the answer to offer another alternative - `sequence`.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention there is no method like that on vavr, however you could made some workarounds:

using tupples:

```
    Try.success(authorizationHeader)
  .map(mapper::hcpFrom)
  .map(hcp -> Tuple.of(hcp, mapper.toSaveNoteRequest(noteId, patientId, requestBody, clock)))
  .map(t2 -> saveNoteUseCase.execute(t2._1(), t2._2()))
  .map(mapper::toHcpNoteResponse)
  .map(response -> accepted().body(response))
  .get();
```

using For with yield:

```
For(Try.success(authorizationHeader).map(mapper::hcpFrom), Try.success(mapper.toSaveNoteRequest(noteId, patientId, requestBody, clock)))
  .yield(saveNoteUseCase::execute)
  .map(mapper::toHcpNoteResponse)
  .map(response -> accepted().body(response))
  .get();
```

using code inside flatMap:

```
Try.success(authorizationHeader)
  .map(mapper::hcpFrom)
  .flatMap(hcp-> Try.of(() -> mapper.toSaveNoteRequest(noteId, patientId, requestBody, clock)).map(saveNoteRequest -> saveNoteUseCase.execute(hcp, saveNoteRequest)))
  .map(mapper::toHcpNoteResponse)
  .map(response -> accepted().body(response))
  .get();
```

And finally using futures(like api, however not recommended)

```
Try.success(authorizationHeader).map(mapper::hcpFrom).toCompletableFuture()
  .thenCombine(Try.success(mapper.toSaveNoteRequest(noteId, patientId, requestBody, clock)).toCompletableFuture(), saveNoteUseCase::execute)
  .thenApply(mapper::toHcpNoteResponse)
  .thenApply(response -> accepted().body(response))
  .join();
```

Kind regards.